# Calculate price selects to a textarea with a button

Tags: javascript, php, html, select

I want bring the value of the label "precio" in the selects, make the sum of this values and put into the `textarea` "cuenta" after click the `button` "añadir al pedido".
The `label` "value" of the selects it's saved in the `textarea` "pedido"

```js
                    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
                    <script>

                    function calcular(){
                    var cuenta=0.00:
                    
                    $('#pedido').val($('#pedido').val()+"\n"+$('#Pizzas option:selected').text());
var newPrice=cuenta;
                     var newPrice+=parseFloat($(this).find('#Pizzas option:selected').attr('precio'));
    
                    $('#pedido').val($('#pedido').val()+"\n"+$('#Bebidas option:selected').text());
var newPrice+=parseFloat($(this).find('#Bebidas option:selected').attr('precio'));
$("#cuenta").html(newPrice);
                }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Pizzas" name="Pizzas" class="form-control" >
<?php
<option value="<?php echo $datos[0];?>" precio="<?php echo $datos[1];?>"><?php echo $datos[0];?></option>

 <?php
           }
 ?>
 </select>
 
<select id="Bebidas" name="Bebidas" class="form-control" >
<?php
<option value="<?php echo $datos[0];?>" precio="<?php echo $datos[1];?>"><?php echo $datos[0];?></option>

     <?php
            }
     ?>
  </select>
<div class="col-12">
                            <div style="padding-left:20px;">
                            <textarea name="pedido" class="form-control" id="pedido" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Pedido" ></textarea>
                        </div>
                            </div>

<div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:10px;">
                            <input type="text" name="cuenta" id="cuenta" class="form-control" placeholder="Cuenta" required  >
                        </div>
                            </div>
  <button name="añadir" type="button" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-xl-4 py-xl-3" onclick="calcular();"><span></span> Añadir al Pedido</button>
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem you are facing?

Comment: if im not wrong, what you want is sum data based on select option and copy it to text area after button clicked, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out.

When you pick any item in select list the select element gets the value of the selected item. Also you shouldn't change textarea inner html, you have to change its value.

There is some nuance of how does js engine works. 
`+"123"` it is the same as `parseInt("123")`. Event better because **parseInt** is going to **drop the reminder**, but `+"12.3" return 12.3`.

If you wrap your select lists in **form** you can add the `require` attribute to them and then check that any of items has been chosen.

```js
let allOrdersTotalSumm = 0
let form = document.querySelector('#order-form')
let pizas = document.querySelector('#Pizzas')
let drinks = document.querySelector('#Drinks')
let priceArea = document.querySelector('#cuenta')
let selectedArea = document.querySelector('#pedido')

document.querySelector('#calc').addEventListener('click', calcTotalSum, false)


function calcTotalSum() {
  // Check that items are picked
  if (!form.reportValidity()) {
    return false
  }
  
  let totalSum = +pizas.value + +pizas.value
  let selectedPiza = pizas.options.item(pizas.options.selectedIndex)
  let selectedDrink = drinks.options.item(drinks.options.selectedIndex)  
  
  selectedArea.value += `${selectedPiza.textContent} with ${selectedDrink.textContent}.Total: ${totalSum}\n`
  allOrdersTotalSumm += totalSum
  priceArea.value = allOrdersTotalSumm
  
  // Reset lists to make a new order
  form.reset()
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
  <form id="order-form">
    <select id="Pizzas" name="Pizzas" class="form-control" data-title="" required>
      <option value="" selected>Please chose your pizza</option>
      <option value="10">Cheesy pizzza</option>
      <option value="12">Cheesy chizz pizzza</option>
      <option value="15">Cheesy beacon cheees pizzza</option>
    </select>

    <select id="Drinks" name="Drinks" class="form-control" data-title="" required>
      <option value="" selected>Please chose your drink</option>
      <option value="7">Coke</option>
      <option value="9">Pepsi</option>
      <option value="12">Milkis</option>
    </select>    
  </form>
</div>

<div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
  <textarea name="pedido" class="form-control" id="pedido" cols="60" rows="10" placeholder="Pedido"></textarea>
</div>

<input type="text" name="cuenta" id="cuenta" class="form-control" placeholder="Cuenta" required>

<button id="calc" name="añadir" type="submit">Añadir al Pedido</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, i think this is what you want.
Just tell me if i got wrong, and tell me if it's what you expected.
Hope it help.

```js
function calcular() {
  let total = parseInt($('#Pizzas').val()) + parseInt($('#Bebidas').val());
  $('#cuenta').val(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Select 1</label>
<select id="Pizzas" name="Pizzas" class="form-control" required>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<br>

<label>Select 2</label>
<select id="Bebidas" name="Bebidas" class="form-control" required>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
</select>

<br><br>
<input type="text" name="cuenta" id="cuenta" class="form-control" placeholder="Cuenta" required>

<button name="añadir" type="button" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-xl-4 py-xl-3" onclick="calcular();"><span></span> Añadir al Pedido</button>
```